# Getting promise not defined error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, webpack, promise, karma-runner, babeljs

I am working on a code that includes promises and I want to run it on IE11.  When I try to run code with IE get promise not defined in Interne Explorer.

I see there are solutions out there with babel-polyfill, however I want to solve this issue without babel-polyfill, what can I do for that ?

webpack configuration

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'partner/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'partner_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Check for all js files
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises are [not supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) in Internet Explorer at all.

You'll *have* to use a polyfill. If you don't want to use `babel-polyfill`, you'll need to use a different one if you still want ES6-style promises.